# pyspark -- an error appears only in IPython, but not in vanila python

Tags: anaconda, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If I start pyspark by typing `/usr/bin/pyspark` in the console, the following sample code runs without any error. However, if I use it with IPython, either by invoking

```
$IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" /usr/bin/pyspark # notebook
```

or by

```
$IPYTHON=1 /usr/bin/pyspark
```

then an exception is raised.

This is the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
# sc is a SparkContex object created when pyspark is invoked
sqc = SQLContext(sc)
```

And this is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f0bbbc9cdb50> in <module>()
      3 from pyspark.sql.types import *
      4 # sc is a SparkContex object created when pyspark is invoked
----> 5 sqc = SQLContext(sc)

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in __init__(self, sparkContext, sqlContext)
     91         """
     92         self._sc = sparkContext
---> 93         self._jsc = self._sc._jsc
     94         self._jvm = self._sc._jvm
     95         self._scala_SQLContext = sqlContext

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_jsc'
```

What causes this error and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the problem exists if I use Anaconda python distribution for Linux:

```
    ~$ ipython --version
    4.0.0
    ~$ python --version
    Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)
```

But, if I disable the anaconda distribution and use Python that comes with the system, everything works well

```
    $ ipython --version
    4.0.0
    $ python --version
    Python 2.7.3
    $ cat /etc/issue
    Debian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l
```

So, the problem is with Anaconda, but still don't know what the problem is

Comment: I'm having the same problem with another package. Very annoying. Have you posted an issue somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the specific error, as it should have the same issue for vanilla and anaconda spark, however, a couple of things you can check:

Make sure the same python version is installed on both your drivers and workers. Different versions can cause issues with serialization.

IPYTHON_OPTS is generally deprecated. Instead I define the following environment variables:

```
# tells pyspark to use notebook
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPS="notebook"
# tells pyspark to use the jupyter executable instead of python. In your case you might want this to be ipython instead
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda2/bin/jupyter
# tells pyspark where the python executable is on the executors. It MUST be the same version of python (preferably with the same packages if you are using them in a UDF or similar
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda2/bin/python
```

Of course I see you are not adding a master to the command line so this would run spark locally if you haven't changed you spark defaults (i.e. no workers).